# QPID: Adding an ad-hoc message consumer to drain unhandled messages in queue

Tags: spring-jms, qpid, spring-scheduled

I have 2 message consumers on a durable QPID queue. These message consumers are created using the following code (I have excluded exception handling in the example below to stay on topic):

```
class MessageConsumer {
    private Session session;
    private Queue queue;
    private final MessageListener listener;
    private final ConditionProvider condition; //can be used to modify the selection string if needed

    public MessageConsumer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String queueName, MessageListener listener, ConditionProvider condition) {
            session = conn.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
    }
//Wakes up every minute and processes messages for the given condition
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "60000", initialDelay = 1000)
public void listen() {
        if (messageConsumer != null) { 
            messageConsumer.close();
        }               
        messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue, condition.getCondition());
        messageConsumer.setMessageListener(listener);
    }
```

- listen() is called whenever I want to change the condition being used to query the queue. Currently, I instantiate 2 instances of the MessageConsumer class on start up. The conditions being provided select messages on the queue which are under and above a specific threshold. The threshold is a property set on the message header. The first listener is used to process messages which have not reached a specific threshold (error rate), while the second one moves messages which have reached the threshold to another queue. Currently, both these work as expected.

Example:

- Consumer 1 - Give me messages where threshold >= 0 and threshold < 10 and process them. The Listener code then does the following: In the event that they cannot be processed, it increments threshold and puts it back on the queue.
- Consumer 2 - Give me messages where threshold > 10 and put them on a different queue.

I now want to add an additional feature i.e. force drain the queue if I know that the reason why messages were not processed has been resolved.

What are valid options for this?

- Does stopping the existing consumers make sense? If so how can I prevent @Scheduled from running and restart @Scheduled after draining the queue
- Adding a new consumer to the same queue and acquire all messages? How can I prevent existing consumers from acquiring these messages?
- Change the condition on the existing consumers to select all messages on the next scheduled run of listen() and drain all messages? Somehow, this is more appealing to me as it takes care of the first 2 options. (Set the query string on one of the consumers as something which will never return any messages and set the query string on the other consumer to return all messages on the queue).

Any help is appreciated.